# Cassandra sstableloader insert if not exists

Tags: cassandra

I've been looking into doing a bulk upload to Cassandra using the sstableloader with CQLSSTableWriter (https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/stable/cassandra/operating/bulk_loading.html#generating-sstables-with-cqlsstablewriter-java-api)

My question is, can I use LWT on an existing table during the creation of these sstables and have that reflected by the sstableloader?

For instance lets say my table has the following data:

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 |
| 2 | 2000 |

Then I run the following code

```
 CQLSSTableWriter.builder()
            .inDirectory()
            .forTable("CREATE TABLE test.table(key bigint, value bigint, PRIMARY KEY(key))")
            .using("INSERT INTO test.table(key, value) VALUES(?, ?) IF NOT EXISTS")
...
writer.addRow(2, 2001);
writer.addRow(3, 3000);
...
```

What will be the final state of the cassandra cluster table?
My hope is that it would be
(1)

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 |
| 2 | 2000 |
| 3 | 3000 |

but I assume if LWT are not supported it would be
(2)

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 |
| 2 | 2001 |
| 3 | 3000 |

Also, this is not specified in the documentation either, but the sstableloader might overwrite the entire table
(3)

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2001 |
| 3 | 3000 |

Which of (1),(2),(3) will be the state of the table after sstableloader runs?

I tried to run locally, but have been unable to get it to run in a non-prod environment